# How to combine multiple less files into one css file?

Tags: css, reactjs, less, react-scripts

I am using `react-script` to build and package my application. Each of my react component is using its own `less` style file and below is the scripts defined in `package.json` to compile these less file to css files:

```
"scripts": {
     "build-css": "node-less-chokidar src/ -o src/",
     "watch-css": "npm run build-css && node-less-chokidar src/ -o src/ --watch --recursive",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build",
    "build": "npm-run-all build-css build-js"
   }
```

the `node-less-chokidar` will compile each less file to a css file with the same file name. Is there a way for me to compile all less files into one `css` file. So I just need to import this big css file in my entry.js file. And if there is a different theme for my website, I just need to replace this big css for theme plugins.

Comment: Reference all of your `.less` files from a master `.less` file and tell compiler to use master file.

Comment: In this way, it combines all the less into one css file, but the watcher doesn't watch the file change in each separate less file. Is there a way to make the watcher works?

Comment: tell your watcher to watch the whole directory

Comment: it will generate each less for each css if I watch the whole directory. I want to compile multiple less into one css file

Comment: if your child files are partials (`_somefile.less`), the compiler should not compile separate files